# Light in my house without a source

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I built a pretty big house in minecraft pe, and it has a second level over half the house. The part under the second level is completely dark when there is no torches, but the second level as well as the half of the house not covered by a second level are lit up completely by themselves, as if there is no roof and it's just sunlight. There are no light sources anywhere in my house to cause this, and there are no windows to let sunlight in. Why is my house lit up?

Comment: Sometimes blocks can act as if they are "transparent", and the game lets the light in. However this is only visual, and the light levels are actually pretty low, which will allow mobs to spawn

Answer (score 1):

It may have been there from a previous light source, as Minecraft does have glitches. If you exit Minecraft and reopen it, the glitch will most likely be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a bug if you don't have any 'transparent' blocks in your house. A transparent block is a block that lets light through visually. But mobs can still spawn as the light levels are still quite low.